# Extjs rowediting change time format after save

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, date-format

This is my code

```
{
    text: "Entrance Time",
    dataIndex: "entrance_time",
    id: "cl_absence_entrance_time",
    editor: {
        xtype: "timefield",
        format: "H:i"
    },
    format: "H:i",
    width: 200
}
```

but the result is

> Tue Jan 01 2008 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIT)

how to change that become 07:00 ? please help me. Thank you

Comment: You can set a renderer for your column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a renderer to convert the Date or just use DateColumn:

```
{
    xtype: 'datecolumn', 
    format : "H:i"
    // ...
}
```